# What is the weak* limit of the Girsanov density associated to drift $F(t)=Ct$?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\mu_0$ be standard Wiener measure on $C[0,T]$. Let $F_C(t)=Ct$ and consider the corresponding Girsanov measure
$$\frac{d\mu_C}{d\mu_0}=\exp\left(CB(T)-\frac12C^2T\right)$$

What is the weak* limit of this measure as $C\to \infty$? We know that the space of signed Borel measures on $C[0,T]$ is compact so we have that $\mu_C$ has a convergence subsequence. I suspect it converges to the zero measure. Because for any $B(T)$ and any $T$, the limit of the density is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability measure $\mu_C$ does not converge to any measure as $C\to\infty$. One way to see this is to note that
$$f_C(u):=\int_{C[0,T]} e^{iu x(T)}\,\mu_C(dx)=e^{iCTu-Tu^2/2}$$
for all real $u$, because $f_C$ is the characteristic function of the random variable $B(T)+CT$. So, for any sequence of real numbers $C_n$ converging to $\infty$, the sequence of the functions $f_{C_n}$ does not converge to any function and thus the sequence of the measures $\mu_{C_n}$ does not converge to any measure.

Another way to come to the same conclusion is to note that for the cdf $F_C$ of $B(T)+CT$ and all real $z$ we have $F_C(z)\to0$ as $C\to\infty$; that is, $F_C$ converges to the cdf of the zero measure on $\mathbb R$. However, a sequence $(\nu_k)$of probability measures can only converge to a probability measure $\nu$, because then $1=\int1\,d\nu_k\to\int1\,d\nu$.